# Border bottom in a horizontal scroll with a white space between them

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a custom horizontal scroll. I would like to display a border bottom in the horizontal scroll but separated, because I get it without space between them. This is my current code:

```css
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac dictum ipsum. Vestibulum a ligula magna. Sed id justo eu nibh pharetra hendrerit vel nec ante. Proin ultrices ante quis erat pulvinar maximus. Quisque id arcu odio. Donec sit amet augue
  urna. Proin lectus ligula, aliquam a velit eu, molestie tempor ipsum. Ut ac neque aliquet nulla aliquet facilisis. Donec ac ultrices augue. In nec augue ullamcorper, tristique enim a, mollis lectus. Curabitur in sodales erat. Suspendisse at egestas
  urna, et elementum arcu. Aliquam dapibus ut neque quis consectetur. Etiam at lectus id odio finibus maximus et a nisi.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you able to edit the HTML?
- Can't you just add a wrapper div?

```css
#Wrap{
  width:200px;
  padding-bottom:6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#Inner {
  position:relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
/*Custom Scrollbar*/
#Inner::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#Inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 6px;
}
#Inner::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrap">
  <div id="Inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac dictum ipsum. Vestibulum a ligula magna. Sed id justo eu nibh pharetra hendrerit vel nec ante. Proin ultrices ante quis erat pulvinar maximus. Quisque id arcu odio. Donec sit amet augue
    urna. Proin lectus ligula, aliquam a velit eu, molestie tempor ipsum. Ut ac neque aliquet nulla aliquet facilisis. Donec ac ultrices augue. In nec augue ullamcorper, tristique enim a, mollis lectus. Curabitur in sodales erat. Suspendisse at egestas
    urna, et elementum arcu. Aliquam dapibus ut neque quis consectetur. Etiam at lectus id odio finibus maximus et a nisi.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution: add padding and then the border-bottom

```
div {
     overflow-x: auto;
     white-space: nowrap;
     width: 200px;
     padding: 16px 0px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Another solution consists on adding a wrapper and creating a new div that will be used to have the separated border bottom, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        div {
            overflow-x: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 200px;
        }

        div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        div::-webkit-scrollbar {
            height: 6px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #000;
        }
        .border-bottom{
            margin-top: 8px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac dictum ipsum. Vestibulum a ligula magna. Sed id justo
           eu nibh pharetra hendrerit vel nec ante. Proin ultrices ante quis erat pulvinar maximus. Quisque id arcu odio. Donec
           sit amet augue urna. Proin lectus ligula, aliquam a velit eu, molestie tempor ipsum. Ut ac neque aliquet nulla aliquet
           facilisis. Donec ac ultrices augue. In nec augue ullamcorper, tristique enim a, mollis lectus. Curabitur in sodales
           erat. Suspendisse at egestas urna, et elementum arcu. Aliquam dapibus ut neque quis consectetur. Etiam at lectus
           id odio finibus maximus et a nisi.
        </div>
        <div class="border-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```